# Saving output layer using Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-toolbox

Why when I try to save my layer in destination gdb (I pass path) does it save in default.gdb?

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""

    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        name="Input Features",
        displayName="Area",
        direction="Input",
        datatype="DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType="Required")

    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        name="Output Features",
        displayName="Output Features Class",
        direction="Output",
        datatype="DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType="Required")

    param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
        name="Input Number0",
        displayName="Cell Size Width",
        direction="Input",
        datatype="Double",
        parameterType="Required")

    param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
        name="Input Number1",
        displayName="Cell Size Height",
        direction="Input",
        datatype="Double",
        parameterType="Required")

    param4 = arcpy.Parameter(
        name="O",
        displayName="O",
        direction="Input",
        datatype="DEFeatureClass",
        parameterType="Required")

    parameters = [param0, param1, param2, param3, param4]

    return parameters

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""

    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

    # teritory
    inputFeatureClass = parameters[0].valueAsText

    # my output
    outputFeatureClass = parameters[1].valueAsText 
    outPath = os.path.basename(outputFeatureClass)

    arcpy.AddMessage(outputFeatureClass)

    cellWidth = parameters[2].value

    cellHeight = parameters[3].value

    o = parameters[4].valueAsText

    # my workspace require to fishnet
    # arcpy.env.workspace = outputFeatureClass

    # when I will be save file, each of them will be overwriting existing file about same name
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    origin, yAxis, opposite = coordinates(inputFeatureClass)

    # create fishnet
    fishnet = arcpy.CreateFishnet_management("in_memory/Fishnet", origin, yAxis, cellWidth, cellHeight, '0', '0',
                                             opposite, 'LABELS', inputFeatureClass, 'POLYGON')
    # add field for id
    arcpy.AddField_management(fishnet, 'idField', 'LONG')

    # add id sequence
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fishnet, ['idField']) as cursor:
        i = 1
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = i
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            i += 1
    del cursor

    # clip a final fishnet
    finalFishnet = arcpy.Clip_analysis(fishnet, inputFeatureClass,
                                       outPath)  

    # create dict for results
    score = {}

    # adding every key value equal 0
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(finalFishnet, ['idField']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            score[row[0]] = 0
    del cursor

    oFunction(o, finalFishnet, score)

    addResultFunction(finalFishnet, score)

    return
```

[image]

After execute

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not specify the output correctly. You extract `outPath` from `parameter 1`. Your fishnet is sent to in_memory but it is the final Clip that is creating the output. If you look at the [syntax section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm#GUID-373858DC-75BF-4816-880B-B27DFD0DB1E6) of the clip tool, it's third parameter is a FEATURECLASS but you provide only a BASENAME (but rather confusingly called it `outPath`) to the clip tool. This tool also does NOT honour workspace as it does not appear in the [environment setting](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm#GUID-EE793288-3684-4FCC-800D-6190900AD835) of this tools.  So you need to provide a full path to the FeatureClass which is you `parameter 1`. If you review the code section of this tool help you will see how to call this tool correctly.